# Means, CI's and post-hoc testing from posterior densities

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, post-hoc

I have generated posterior distributions of several estimates by combining a series of chains from Bayesian regression models. Specifically, they are merged chains from `MCMCglmm` models.

These models are of the form `y ~ a + b + c`, where `a` and `b` are factors with multiple levels, and `c` is a continuous variable. From these posterior distributions I can calculate the estimate (mean) and its confidence interval.

For the continuous variable this is sufficient. However, for the factors I would like to know the predicted mean and CI for each of the factor levels. Ideally, I would also like to test which levels are different from each other.

Example code in R:

```
library(MCMCglmm)
m <- MCMCglmm(mpg ~ factor(cyl) + factor(vs) + wt, data = mtcars)
d <- as.data.frame(test$Sol)
```

Can one use `d` to:

- calculate the means of each level of `cyl` and `vs`?
- test whether the different levels of `cyl` differ significantly from each other?

(I mainly interested in knowing *if* and *how* I can do this in a statistical sense. R code would be appreciated, but it is not the focus of my question.)

Comment: You seem to have a mixture of statistical questions (which are on-topic) and coding questions (which are not). Can you clarify the statistical issues you are puzzling over and ask the other ones elsewhere, perhaps on R-help or StackOverflow for both of which you will need a reproducible example